# Give wpf appbar "higher priority" than the windows taskbar

Tags: wpf, space, taskbar, docking, appbar

I have experimented with making an appbar, and wiring the interop code to a wpf window (With help from CodeProject), and it works great! But there's something more I want to do. I want the dock setting of the window I am docking to "push around" the taskbar, i.e., if its width is 50, and its dock is left, then the taskbar should be 50 pixels shorter, and start 50 pixels away from the left side of the screen. Perhaps the best example I can find of this is this (old) photo from an early Longhorn build of windows:

[image]

In this picture, the sidebar makes the taskbar shorter. Is this possible, and how do I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: I am fairly certain that the taskbar is one of those things they've locked down pretty tightly.  You'd need to disable explorer and install an alternate shell that let you alter the width of the taskbar... or alternatively, perma-hide the taskbar and replace it with a dock or your own dock.  W7 SP1 broke some perma-hide options, but of course just killing explorer off will make the task bar disappear and not come back until explorer is started up again.

Comment: Well, I certainly want to keep explorer. Is there a way to hack the taskbar's window handle to make it do what I want? Because what I'm making simply needs to be around all the edges of the screen.

Comment: It's worth a shot, but I don't have any advice to give on how to accomplish it :)  If you open up UIspy, you will see that the taskbar is assigned all the things a window normally is - ClassName, ProcessID, BoundingRect, etc.  It wouldn't surprise me if the taskbar has been protected from interaction in some way, but perhaps with some WIN32 judo it can be done.  I'm interested in your results if you get anywhere!